# How to use RSA private key for TripleDES encryption?

Tags: rsa

Our goal is to send SOAP messages to a web service, signing these messages using TripleDesRSA15 algorithm.

Web service staff sent us a .pfx file, where certificate for encryption is stored. I'm able to extract private key from this certificate and its first line is `BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY`.

Then I store this private key in a server and use it for encryption using python:

```
pkey=open("pkey.key", "rb").read()

from pyDes import *
pyDes=triple_des(pkey)
```

But python module pyDes complaints: 
`*** ValueError: Invalid triple DES key size. Key must be either 16 or 24 bytes long`

Did I use wrong key or use it in a wrong way?

Comment: I'm confused why you used `pyDes.triple_des()` on a RSA private key.

Comment: I am not convinced you have the wrong key. See [MS reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.security.securityalgorithmsuite.tripledesrsa15(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 4):

> How to use RSA private key for TripleDES encryption?

**You don't!**

RSA and 3DES are two *completely* different encryption algorithms with completely different properties. For a start, RSA uses a key *pair* (encryption and decryption key, respectively; this is known as asymmetric or [public-key cryptography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography)) while 3DES (because DES) uses only a single key for both encryption and decryption (called [symmetric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric-key_algorithm) cryptography).

If you don't know exactly what you are doing (and not to be disparaging, but based on your question, I get the distinct feeling that you don't), you *really* shouldn't be doing encryption on your own. There are just far too many ways to mess up, in ways that puts data at risk, even when using well-known and time-proven algorithms like these (let alone if you are designing something entirely of your own).

Instead, you should delegate the task of data secrecy and authenticity to appropriate libraries, perhaps through Python's TLS support (same as your web browser uses when connecting to a HTTPS server), and just ask for a secure pipe to the remote system. The odds of getting that wrong are vastly smaller.

Comment: I think the _RSA15_ refers to using the PKCS 1.5 key padding algorithm.

Comment: Thanks! I'll contact web service stuff and ask to send me correct keys...